# Best wiki for dotnetnuke

Tags: vb.net, wiki, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I've tried the wiki that comes with DotNetNuke and we don't like it at all.  Can anyone suggest a better wiki that we could use with DNN 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Canam Wiki 1.5.  Here is a features list:

http://marketplace.dotnetnuke.com/p-875-canam-wiki100.aspx

Comment: Have you had experience with this?  What is your opinion?  It had better be good for $99.

Comment: They offer a 30 day trial.  No, I haven't tried it, but I like the feature set, and I've bought $99 modules for DotNetNuke before.  $99 is nothing if you get what you want and you have more than a trivial number of users and/or portal sites.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.  The DNN wiki is pretty klunky.  We're trying [Dokuwiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki), [Screwturn](http://www.screwturn.eu/), and [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

EDIT:
No, these are not DNN modules.  So they don't integrate directly.  We're going to implement it as wiki.MySite.com rather than www.MySite.com/wiki.  Good comment, @Robert Harvey.

Comment: Do any of these integrate with DNN?

Comment: Dokuwiki and mediawiki are both PHP-based.  Our host can't handle *nix things.  I tried Screwturn.  It doesn't play well with DNN.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated link for Canam Wiki:http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=20507

Comment: Canam Wiki looks like a port of the ScrewTurn wiki. The screen shots at the SnowCovered link above are pretty much identical to ScrewTurn. I use ScrewTurn wiki for my wiki (wiki.dnnstuff.com). I haven't bothered integrating dnnstuff.com with my wiki but you could probably write an authentication provider for ScrewTurn to allow your DNN users to log in with the same username/password.

Comment: @Richard - Agreed, but that would still be a different application. A module is used when you want a solution to work WITHIN your application. A module can use files, tags, etc. from the parent app. Extremely difficult, to say the least, in your setup.